# e-text editor or textmate: What are environmental variables? or in e-text: environment - KEY_____ VALUE_____

Tags: editor, text-editor, environment-variables, key

I'm sure this has to do with programming/coding, in e-text editor, under edit>settings, there's a tab called "environment", when clicked on you see 2 columns, the left if titled KEY, and the right is titled VALUE. I Googled it and I think it might be the equivalent of textmate's [Environment Variables](http://manual.macromates.com/en/environment_variables.html), [here's their wikipedia page that shows a screenshot](http://www.e-texteditor.com/wiki/index.php/Projects#Project_Specific_Environment_Variables). I just don't understand what 'Project Specific Environment Variables' are, and what you would use them for, an example? How would I use this?

I'm pretty sure this will be an acceptable question for stackoverflow, if not, then I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just don't understand what *'Project Specific Environment Variables'* are, and what you would use them for

Most command line compiler tools uses environment varibales to control the compile and build process.

For example **INCLUDE**, **LIB** and **LIBPATH** are typical environment variables used by Windows based *C/C++* command line compilers.

> [give] an example?

Take for example the *Microsoft C/C++* compiler. To run this compiler from the command line you need to setup a larger number of environment variables.

Infact this enter code herecompile needs so many environment variables, Microsoft even provides the *vsvars32.bat* file which does nothing more than correctly setup the environment variables.